# Silence docker rm command in bash

Tags: bash, docker, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I tried `docker container rm container-name > /dev/null` but this still prints `Error: No such container: container-name`. I'm trying to silence this error in my bash script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Send stderr to /dev/null:

```
docker container rm container-name 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: thanks, that works, but how do I silence both the error and success at the same time?

Comment: Rather, replace `2>` with `&>`.